# Always find phone state receive change

Tags: android

i write a broadcast receiver to find when phone state is changed. it worked successfully when app is running. after a second time that app is removed from recent my broadcast is not worked.
how i can fixed it?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your broadcast will only work if your app process will be in the memory. So, when the app process is killed i.e. the app is removed from recent apps then the broadcast won't be delivered to your app.

If you want to run your broadcast even if the app is removed from the recent apps, then you should implement a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) and register your broadcast there.  So, even if the app is removed from recent, the foreground service will remain active and will be able to receive broadcasts.

Comment: i create foreground service:```<service
            android:name=".service.CallForegroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall" />``` in service register the broadcast. i remove declare broadcast in manifest but not working

Comment: If you would have followed this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-service then it should work. can you post your manifest file and service class for more information on this issue?

Comment: https://file.io/09n41RkWTgj8 -> Manifest.xml , https://file.io/6C8Vfc2BZJWG 
 -> foregroundService

Comment: Your Service class is not a ForegroundService i.e. it doesn't show a persistent notification when service is started. See this - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start

Comment: i confused. sorry could you said step by step?

Comment: https://file.io/7fqEfZcZF5aA -> i change service, is it true?

Comment: Yes, the service code looks fine. Is it working at your end as well? You will see a persistent notification on the notification tray of the device and this notification won't go away even if you remove your app from recents app. You should now also receive PHONE_STATE and NEW_OUTGOING_CALL even the app is not in recent apps.

Comment: it's run always?

Comment: The foreground service runs when the user runs your app atleast for the  first time when the device starts. So, your app will receive the broadcasts only if the foreground service is running (you can check the notification in the notification tray). But the user can force stop the service so make sure the notification shows the appropriate message to user. You can go through Background Execution limits introduced in Android Oreo. See this - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background